# Problem while inserting/appending to a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, insert, append

When I run the following code with `n = 2`, I'm getting `answer = [[2, 2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2, 2]]`.

```
n = int(input())  
answer = [[1]]  
for i in range(2, n+1):
    t = [i]*((2*i)-3)  
    answer.insert(0, t)  
    answer.append(t)     
    for a in answer:
        a.insert(0,i)

print(answer)
```

What I needed is `[[2,2],[2,1],[2,2]]`.

Why is `insert()` adding an extra 2 in the first and last list?

The same happens with `a.append(i)`.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you try to do? Why is `[[2,2],[2,1],[2,2]]` your expected result.

Comment: Hi @SimonFink. My objective was to print a pattern. This was a step in my entire code where i was facing problem. 
Pattern was something like : 222
                                              212
                                              222
Same for n = 3,4,....

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because answer[0] and answer[2] are both referencing the same object, t. If you make changes to answer[0] or answer[2], you're actually making changes to t, and since both are referencing it, t will get modified twice, hence the unexpected result. Try using the copy library or use [i]*((2*i)-3) directly in insert and append instead.

```
n=int(input())  
answer=[[1]]  
for i in range(2, n+1):
    answer.insert(0, [i]*((2*i)-3))  
    answer.append([i]*((2*i)-3))     
    for a in answer:
        a.insert(0,i)

print(answer)
```

or

```
import copy

n=int(input())  
answer=[[1]]  
for i in range(2, n+1):
    t = [i]*((2*i)-3)
    answer.insert(0, copy.copy(t))  
    answer.append(copy.copy(t))     
    for a in answer:
        a.insert(0,i)

print(answer)
```

Comment: I've put the example code the implementations I suggested, maybe you could use it instead.